# Installing the haskell-platform on the Nvidia Jetson TK1 (ARM Architecture)

Tags: haskell, arm, tegra

Running `lsb_release -s -d` on the Jetson TK1 gives me `Ubuntu 14.04 LTS`

So I tried `sudo apt-get install haskell-platform` and `sudo apt-get install ghc` and with both I get an error that it is unable to locate the package. So I enabled the universe repository as I saw on a stackoverflow post for installing the haskell-platform for ubuntu 14.04. I still get the same result.

I see some people mentioning the got the haskell-platform to install on raspberry pis easily and that GHC now has good support for ARM but I don't see a way to get the install running on the Jetson TK1. My next option is to build from source, I don't see source for ARM architecture on the GHC or Haskell platform website.

I know there is also cross compiling, I will start messing with that when I see there is no easier way.

Comment: Is it due to armhf vs armel?

Comment: You don't need any ARM-specific code for installing from source. I could build ghc-7.8 on my Raspberry π just fine, though it took ages. What you do need however is an already-installed GHC, normally obtained by installing Haskell-platform from binary distribution... so there's the problem.

Comment: @Hamzeh, Have you managed to install GHC?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to compile GHC7.8.3 on the Jetson K1 and Adapteva Parallella.
I wrote a [blog post about it here](http://arnon.dk/ive-managed-to-compile-ghc-7-8-3-on-an-nvidia-tegra-jetson-k1/) which is more verbose, but here's a summarized rundown of what I did:

1. You will need GHC7.6.3 or earlier to bootstrap the compilation. I ran
   `sudo apt-get install ghc automake build-essential cabal-install groff`
2. You’ll also need Alex and Happy, `sudo apt-get install alex happy`.
   I also installed them in Cabal, cabal update && cabal install alex happy
3. I decided to compile with llvm, clang and gold linker, because gcc wouldn’t compile all the way.
   `sudo apt-get install llvm clang binutils`
4. Edit mk/build.mk. I uncommented the line about quick-llvm compilation
   `BuildFlavour = quick-llvm`.
   You'll also need to replace appearances of `-H64m` with `-H32m`
5. `perl boot` and `sudo ./configure --with-clang=/usr/bin/clang --with-ar=/usr/bin/ar`
6. Because there is a linker issue, obtain the following script that will switch between standard ld and gold: `https://gist.githubusercontent.com/bgamari/9399430/raw/build-ghc-arm.sh`
7. chmod ugo+rx build-ghc-arm.sh
   `sudo /build-ghc-arm.sh -j6`
8. `sudo make install`